# How long can the Compression (Ex) ability keep the creature compressed?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, magic-items

So I came across [Belt of the Weasel](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/wondrous-items/wondrous-items/a-b/belt-of-the-weasel/) and one of the perks of getting the item is gaining the [Compression(Ex)](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/rules-for-monsters/universal-monster-rules#TOC-Compression-Ex-) ability. I was wondering how long the effects of compression last. To my understanding of the way it is worded, it seems like you can use it for a short duration to pass through a small space but what if some one wants to stay compressed for let's say a day. Would the ability allow him to do that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Yes**

There is no duration or limit in the ability, so it is always active. You are just magically able to fit into small spaces for however long you want. You probably wouldn't be comfortable after a day of being compressed, but there is nothing mechanically keeping you from doing it.